# Form submit problem

Tags: 7, forms

I have no idea why my form submit only work if I put on screen values of $form argument.

If I add:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($form);
echo '</pre>'
```

to my submit function I am getting new 'page' with this data printed out, but when I uncomment this nothing seems to work, I see form page again.

```
function gate_check_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $post = $form['#post'];
//    echo '<pre>';
//    print_r($form);
//    echo '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($post); //gives nothing
    echo '</pre>';

    $day = intval($post['gate_day']);
    $month = intval($post['gate_month']);
    $year = intval($post['gate_year']);
    $isRemember = isset($post['gate_remember_me']);
    if ($day && $month && $year) {
        $allowed_age = (int) variable_get('gate_minimal_age', 18);
        $min_born_time  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),   date("d"),   date("Y") - $allowed_age);
        $born_time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($min_born_time);
        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($born_time);
        echo '</pre>';
        if ($min_born_time >= $born_time) {
            echo 'yes';
           sess_write(GATE_SESSION_NAME, TRUE);
           if ($isRemember) {
               set_cookie(GATE_COOKIE_NAME, sha1($born_time + srand()), time()+60*60*24*7);
           }
           drupal_goto('/');

        } 
        echo 'no';
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you should use `echo "<pre>" . print_r($form,1) . "</pre>"`.

Comment: It does nothing

Comment: I suggest you to use the devel module and the dpm function.

    dpm($form_values, 'form_values');
    dpm($form, 'form');

Comment: You should not use `sess_write()` to write data in the session; it's enough you use `$_SESSION[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it wrong*. You should read the [Form API quickstart](http://drupal.org/node/751826) guide to understand how to use the validate and submit handlers properly.

* For several reasons, the biggest one being that you are using #post, which is a big no-no. You should use sanitized values from `$form_state['values']` instead.